# Numeric value out of range: 1264 in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

My Error,

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'pro_price_dis' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `rp_cal_table` (`productID`, `RSP_dis`, `RSP_mar`, `RRP_mar`, `cont_RRP_mar`, `cont_RSP_mar`, `sea_cloud_price`, `sea_cloud_sal_price`, `pro_price_dis`, `mar_pro_price_dis`, `pro_price_mar`, `mar_pro_price_mar`, `sal_pro_price`, `mar_sal_pro_price`, `method`, `DB_price`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (32, 0, 0, 0.4, 630.4, 0, 0.30, 0, 1103.2, 0.14285714285714, 1153.1707317073, 0.18, 0, 0, , 1153.1707317073, 2017-04-12 10:38:56, 2017-04-12 10:38:56))

my datatype is `decimal(8,5)`  but still i am getting this error.

how can i igone and insert if it is more also after .(Dot).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The value of the column is

```
1103.2
```

but you mention the data type is `decimal(8,5)` which means the max number allowed is

```
999.99999
```

since `8` is the **total** precision minus decimal places

Comment: Suggestion for alternative?

Comment: Sure. Store smaller numbers.

Comment: I would have though perhaps try double?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe: Just use a different decimal. For instance:`decimal(15,5)`