# SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value

Tags: mysql, laravel

in my decimal from WAMP server is decimal (5,2)
My QueryException:

SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'converted_1000ml' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `inventory_databanks` (`product_desc`, `nc_os`, `ncos_value`, `del`, `ei`, `sa`, `wh`, `bi`, `brand`, `variant`, `type`, `content`, `conversion_1000ml`, `**converted_1000ml**`, `os`, `bo`, `peso_sales`, `bo_case`, `os_case`, `del_case`, `wh_case`, `sa_case`, `price`, `facing`, `maker`, `merchandiser_name`, `complete_address`, `source_type`, `payroll_period`, `cellphone`, `schedule`, `area`, `region`, `province`, `city_municipality`, `outlet`, `edi_branch`, `salesman`, `ns_case1`, `ns_case2`, `ns_case3`, `ns_bottles1`, `ns_bottles2`, `ns_bottles3`, `ns_date1`, `ns_date2`, `ns_date3`, `date_started`, `inventory_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Emperador_Light 1000mL Light Brandy, With Stocks, With Stocks, **2400**, 4734, 78, **4656**, 245, Emperador_Light, Brandy, Original, 1000, 1.00, 4734.00, 0, 0, -229790, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 110.00, 13, EDI, Rodolfo Siongco Jr, null, From Inventory Sheet, 01/16/2018 - 01/31/2018, 09303243249, T-TH-S, Central Luzon, Region III, Bataan, Mariveles, CORA'S, Pampanga Branch, Angelito Quetua, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2018-01-31, 2018-01-31, 2018-01-31, 2018-01-16, 1970-01-01, 2018-02-08 08:49:48, 2018-02-08 08:49:48))

How can i fix this? bold numbers i think this is my problem

Comment: Please show migration file for this table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numeric value out of range: 1264 in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367408/numeric-value-out-of-range-1264-in-mysql)

Comment: i think i change from my decimal because i input 4000 but i dont know what can i input

Comment: add the result of  `desc YOURTABLE` information to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

decimal (5,2) has a range of -999.99 to 999.99. You will have to change that column in order to hold large values.

> salary DECIMAL(5,2)
>
> In this example, 5 is the precision and 2 is the scale. The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.
>
> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)