# Regex patter for SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'abc' at row 1

Tags: regex, laravel, double, precision

I am writing validation rule for double data type numeric value column in Laravel but following regex is not validating and error goes to database, can you please suggest which rule is right

```
 $data=Request::all();
     $validator = Validator::make($data, [
             'abc' => array(
            'required',
            'regex:/^[-+]?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/u'
        ),
        ]);
```

This patter also not working. `/\d+\.\d*|\.?\d+/`

Comment: What is the expected behavior of `regex:/^[-+]?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/u`? Please share *"valid"* VS *"invalid"* sample values/inputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[22003\]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681491/sqlstate22003-numeric-value-out-of-range-1264-out-of-range-value)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa no